# .NET C# Double equivalent System.Numerics.BigInteger

Tags: c#, .net, pi

I'm am currently writing a program that calculates the digits of pi, and I have a problem. After three iterations the number of correct digits exceeds the memory available in a double.
I heard of the System.Numerics.BigInteger type (in System.Numerics.dll), but I need to use floating point numbers. I do not understand the algorithm well enough to use integers.

It would be great if a version of the BigInteger exists which supports a decimal point.
Below I have put my C# code:

```
var a = 1.0;
var b = 1 / Math.Sqrt(2);
var t = 0.25;
var p = 1.0;
double anext, bnext, tnext, pnext;
int count = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= accuracy; i++ )
{
            anext = (a + b) / 2;
            bnext = Math.Sqrt(a * b);
            tnext = (t - p * ((a - anext) * (a - anext)));
            pnext = 2 * p;

            a = anext;
            b = bnext;
            t = tnext;
            p = pnext;

            var pi = ((a + b) * (a + b)) / (4 * t);

            Console.WriteLine("Iteration = " + i.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Pi =        " + pi + "\n\n\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Here is a big number implementation I found via google: http://www.boyet.com/Articles/PiCalculator.html.  It seems tailored exactly for this application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The BigInteger class was written by Melitta Andersen of the BCL team, her first project.  It was actually shipped in .NET 3.5 but was hidden, the class was marked *internal*.  Not to become public until .NET 4.0.  She also wrote a floating point version, called BigRational.  Similar problem, didn't make it into .NET 4.0.  These are strange and unexplainable decisions whose reasoning I'm not privy to.

Nevertheless, the source code for BigRational is available.  You can download [it here](http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases/view/42782).

Comment: I was going to say "What about `BigIrrational`?" but then thought twice about it. :) Great answer! +1

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you for the download link. Would you happen to know where BigInteger source code can be downloaded? I have already downloaded the source for .NET 4 but it is not included for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to calculate Pi to an arbitrary number of digits of precision, then *none* of the numeric types available will be valid. You're going to have to use a string (or, preferably, a `StringBuilder`) and compute the number digit-by-digit.

Comment: ewww, Strings. Worst possible choice in every respect. :(

Comment: @Mehrdad: Really? Worse than a `DateTime`? Or a `SqlConnection`? While there are more efficient ways of storing the data, if the OP doesn't understand the algorithm well enough to do that, then using a string will be sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, I guess a `SqlConnection` would be worse... I stand corrected.