# Add a digit into a double

Tags: c#, math, double, modulo

I'm trying to make a complex division calculator.

I have a double[] and I want to add the mod of the previous array position to the start of the next number.

For example, if I were to divide 1951 with 2, I split 19 and 51 into the double[], (meaning double[0] = 19 and double[1] = 51) and want to add the mod of 19 with 2 to the start of the next position, in this case add "1" to double[1] and have it equal to 151 to continue. Example code matching with the examples above.

```
    static double[] number = new double[2];
    static int toDiv;    

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ///TESTING ONLY
        number[0] = 19;
        number[1] = 51;

    }//end of main

    void Calculate()
    {
            for (int i= 0; i<number.Length; i++)
            {

                if (number[i] % numsToDiv[0] == 0)
                {//if the program gets in here, % = 0

                    if (i - 1 == number.Length)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }//end of if (i-1==number.Length)
                    else
                    {
                        toDiv = (int)number[i] % numsToDiv[0];

                    }//end of else
                }//end of if
            }//end of "i" for
    }//end of Calculate()
```

Comment: because I'm going for very high, high digit numbers, so this is necessary as a single double variable cant store as many digits (yes, this much >.<)

Comment: Please take a loot at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189835/net-c-sharp-double-equivalent-system-numerics-biginteger - in particular the answer and the link to [BigRational](http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases/view/42782).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen this looks very useful... only one question, do you know if by arbitrarily large, it means it can hold millions of digits? because if thats the case, it narrows down my program a lot

Answer (score 0):

lets first create a function that returns the 0s needed to split the numerator into two and find the 0s to add for placing the mod value of the next number

```
int zeroPlaceHolder(ZerosNeeded){
    int zeros = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < ZerosNeeded;i++)
       zeros *= 10;
    return zeros;
}
```

find the length of digits in the numerator
i would go about this by changing the numerator to string then find the length of the string

```
int numerator = 1951;
int denominator = 2;
//this is a convetion used in programming so am assuming C# has this too
int len = numerator.toString().length;
```

split the numerator into 2 using half the 0s of the digit, this will give us both parts of the split

```
int divider = zeroPlaceHolder(len/2); 
//the first part can be found by
number[0] = numerator/divider;
//second part
number[1] = numerator%divider;
//find the number needed to shift the mod of previous to first digit of next
len = number[1].toString().length;
divider = zeroPlaceHolder(len);
//shift the mod of the 1st number(number[0])/denominator to the right
number[1] = number[1] + (divider * (number[0]%denominator));
```